# Use of unassigned local variable total

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the sum of all the integers from 1 to 1001 that are divisible by 2

```
private static int elevens()
{   
    int initial=0;
    int total;

    for(int i=0; i<1002;i++)
    {
        if (i%11==0)
        {
            total=initial+ i;
        }
    }
    return total; //line where error occurs     
}
```

Comment: In the code you pasted, you have a superfluous closing bracket '}' before the *return* statement. Also, see answer by Daniel Mann.

Answer (score 5):

You have to assign a value to `total`. Change your variable declaration to `int total = 0;`.

The compiler doesn't know that there's guaranteed to be a number between 0 and 1002 that's divisible by 11. If there wasn't, then you'd never have a value assigned to your `total` variable. If there's no value in the variable, what are you returning? The compiler is letting you know that there exists the possibility of the variable being returned with no value, which isn't allowed.

Comment: thanks it worked. Will you be willing to help me with another problem in my code?